# SQL Server | Flagging an instance based on multiple lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work in claims data, which has multiple lines in the database.

For example:
Claim: **12345** has **5** lines to it, each paying a different amount for different services.

The issue I am trying to resolve is that each line can either be auto-priced or manually priced. I am trying to flag the data using CASE/WHEN logic so that ANY claim with a manual price flag is present at all on the claim, the FLAG will set the entire claim as "MANUALLY PRICED".

Here is an example of how the data looks in the datawarehouse:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADB6J.jpg

Here is how I would expect the logic to produce:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8DkY.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could accomplish this.

```
select CLAIMID
    , CLAIMLINE
    , USEMANUAL
    , IsManual.PricingUsed
from Claims c
cross apply
(
    select max(case when USEMANUAL = 'Y' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as PricingUsed
    from Claims c2
    where c2.CLAIMID = c.CLAIMID
) as IsManual
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully :) I am not familiar with the cross apply, i will have to look more into that! Thank you so much.

Comment: You can read more about APPLY here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/ And for part 2. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window function Max() over  (SQL Server 2012+)

```
Declare @YourTable table (ClaimID int,ClaimLine int,UseManual varchar(10))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(12345,1,'N'),
(12345,2,'N'),
(12345,3,'N'),
(12345,4,'Y'),
(12345,5,'N')

Select *
      ,Manual_Priceing_Used = case when max(UseManual) over (Partition By ClaimID)='Y' then 'Yes' else 'No' end
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
   ClaimID  ClaimLine   UseManual   Manual_Priceing_Used
    12345   1           N           Yes
    12345   2           N           Yes
    12345   3           N           Yes
    12345   4           Y           Yes
    12345   5           N           Yes
```